# Switch nested array values with keys, and reverse tally accordingly

Tags: php, arrays

I've taken a few photographs and I've tagged people as being in them. I have an array whose keys are `photo_id`'s and whose values are arrays of `person_id`'s tagged in the photograph:

```
Array
(
    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 177
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
            [1] => 4
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
            [1] => 4
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [0] => 934
            [1] => 935
            [2] => 234
        )
)
```

What I want is an array with the `person_id`'s as keys and the photographs they are tagged in as values. For example, person **27** is in photographs **26** and **27**. How would I go about creating this new array? Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you storing this in an array?  This seems like data best suited for a relational database. Can you show what attempts you have made to reach a solution (i.e. have you even tried a brute force looping approach?)

Comment: @MikeBrant These values are coming from Zenfolio, my gallery host. This is just a snapshot of my array: I have more than 500 photographs, so yes, ideally I'd like to put the values in a database. I am a complete novice, so I know next to nothing about what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll simply need to loop over your array and create a new array using the `person_id` as your new key and `n` number of entries which are your `photo_id`s:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($original_array as $photo_id => $values) {
    foreach($values as $person_id) {
        // initialize array key if it doesn't already exist
        if(!array_key_exists($person_id, $new_array)) {
            $new_array[$person_id] = array();
        }
        // add photo id to the array
        $new_array[$person_id][] = $photo_id;
    }
}
```

Here's a demo: https://eval.in/147879

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `array_walk()` and `in_array()` to get what you need done:

```
$pictures = Array( 19 => [12], 21 => [177], 26 => [27,4], 27 => [27,4], 28 => [934,935,234] );
$included = [];
$person = 27;

//The following line is all you need
array_walk( $pictures, function(&$picture, $pictureId, $params) { 
        if( in_array( $params[1], $picture, TRUE ) )
            array_push( $params[0], $pictureId );
    }, [&$included, $person] ); 

print_r( $included );
```

Will print out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 26
    [1] => 27
)
```

---

If you want to completely reverse the array, then you can use double `foreach` loops to iterate through them:

```
$pictures = [19 => [12], 21 => [177], 26 => [27,4], 27 => [27,4], 28 => [934,935,234] ];
$included = [];
foreach( $pictures as $pictureId => $picture ) {
    foreach( $picture as $personId ) {
        if( !isset( $included[$personId] ) )
            $included[$personId] = [];
        array_push( $included[$personId], $pictureId );
    }
}; 
print_r( $included );
```

The result of this will print:

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
        )

    [177] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
            [1] => 27
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
            [1] => 27
        )

    [934] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
        )

    [935] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
        )

    [234] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
        )

)
```